# How to Unset session item count number

Tags: php, e-commerce, session-variables

Please help , I am practicing to build an eCommerce site and I want that after they successfully ordered the product the item count in the cart icon will go back to 0 and stop all the session. Say I order 3 product so the cart will have an item badge of 3 and returns to 0 when finished. It does return to 0 but when you click the Cart Icon which loads to load_cart.php, it will still load to the previous item I ordered.

from `checkout_action.php >>>>>going to header("location:order_confirmation.php?checkout=success");`

```
<?php session_start();
  if ($_GET['checkout'] =='success'){
  unset($_SESSION['item_count']);
 }
?>
```

this is where I store the cart `add_to_cart.php`

```
<?php session_start();
  $id = $_POST['item_id'];
  $quantity = $_POST['item_quantity'];
  $_SESSION["cart"][$id] = $quantity;
  $_SESSION["item_count"] = array_sum($_SESSION["cart"]);
  echo "<span class='carttxt glyphicon glyphicon-shopping-cart'> SHOP </span> 
     <span class='badge'>" . $_SESSION["item_count"] . "</span>";
```

and I load the cart using this load_cart.php

```
 <?php
 session_start();
 include("includes/head.php");
 include("includes/db_config.php");
 include("includes/jsbottom.php");

 $data = "<table class='table table-striped table-responsive'>
   <thead>
     <tr>
       <th>Product</th>
       <th>Price</th>
       <th>Quantity</th>
       <th>Sub-Total</th>
       <th>Action</th>
       </tr>
     </thead>
   <tbody>";

$grand_total = 0;
foreach($_SESSION['cart'] as $product_id => $quantity) {
$sql = "SELECT * FROM items where id = '$product_id' ";
$result = mysqli_query($conn, $sql);
if(mysqli_num_rows($result) > 0) {
   while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {
     $product_name = $row["product_name"];
     $product_desc = $row["product_desc"];
     $price = $row["price"];
     $image = $row["image"];

     //For computing the sub total and grand total
     $subTotal = $quantity * $price;
     $grand_total += $subTotal;

     $data .="<tr>
             <td>$product_name . <div class='middle'> <img 
            src='$image' style='height:100px;width:100px;'/> </div> </td>
            <td id='price$product_id'> $price</td>
            <td><input type='number' class ='form-control' 
           value = '$quantity' id='quantity$product_id' 
           onchange='changeNoItems($product_id)' min='1' size='5'></td>
           <td id='subTotal$product_id'>$subTotal</td>
           <td><button class='btn btn-danger' 
           onclick='removeFromCart($product_id)'><span class='glyphicon 
           glyphicon-trash' aria-hidden='true'></span> Remove</button></td>
           </tr>";
         }
       }
     }

    $data .="</tbody></table>
      <hr>
      <a href='checkout.php'> <h3 align='right'>Total: &#x20B1; <span 
          id='grandTotal'>$grand_total </span><br><button class='btn btn- 
          success btn-lg'><span class='glyphicon glyphicon-ok-sign'></span> 
          Check Out</button></h3>  </a>
          <hr>";

   echo $data;
?>
```

Comment: you can add $_SESSION['item_count'] = 0 with unset($_SESSION['item_count']);

Comment: On checkout success please check your `if condition` where you are  trying to unset session variable. May be its not getting success values in `If` thats why its failing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well your code is not checking if `$_SESSION['item_count']` is 0. It is fetching the contents of `$_SESSION['cart']`. You need to either check if `$_SESSION['item_count']` is 0 or destroy the `$_SESSION['cart']` for example:

```
<?php session_start();
  if ($_GET['checkout'] =='success') {
  session_destroy();
 }
?>
```

Comment: I am wondering if all the sessions such as login session will also be destroyed

Comment: Yes session_destroy will destroy all session information. If you want to reset the shopping cart session, then you should unset $_SESSION['cart'] using unset($_SESSION['cart'])